# why don't BOTH fullCalendar and datePicker work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

currently the code for the calendar functions, but the datePicker doesn't 
if i copy/paste so that the date picker code comes second it functions, but the calendar doesn't.
fullcalendar source http://fullcalendar.io/ datepicker source  https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max

```
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https:/resources/demos/style.css">
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: +1, maxDate: "+1Y" });
        });
      </script>
    <!--  code above is the code for the datepicker -->


    <!--  code below is the code for the calendar  -->
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='fullcalendar-2.6.1(1)/fullcalendar-2.6.1/fullcalendar.css' />
    <script src='fullcalendar-2.6.1(1)/fullcalendar-2.6.1/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='fullcalendar-2.6.1(1)/fullcalendar-2.6.1/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
    <script src='fullcalendar-2.6.1(1)/fullcalendar-2.6.1/fullcalendar.js'></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
        function(){
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                weekends:false,
                defaultView:'agendaWeek',
                header: {
                    left:'prev,today,next',
                    center:'title',
                    right:'month,agendaWeek'
                },
            });
        });
```

Comment: I did try putting all of the script in the same script tag (neither worked) as well as adding .ready for the datepicker script (no change).

Comment: Total mess there with `link` and `script`.. Put all your `link` tags before loading `scripts`. Keep only one version of `jquery`. There are 2 in fact. `jquery-1.10.2.js` and `jquery.min.js`

Comment: First things first: keep a clean organization of your files. This would help you to see that you include jquery two times. Your css files should be in the head section and your js files as last lines in your body (this optimizes the speed at which your page will be shown for the user).

Comment: Here is a **[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/0wf3f7ss/)** where both works as expected.

Comment: The demo is the same code as in my answer. Please mark it as correct if this solved your issue or update your question to explain whats not working. Otherwise we can't help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out simoultaniously by @Guruprasad and myself, your file inclusions are a mess.

It seems you're new so for this time here's the correct way to do it.
You don't need all the `$(func...` since you're using document.ready event to fire before calling the functions which means that jquery is available at this point.

Hope it helps !

```
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
     <link rel='stylesheet' href='fullcalendar-2.6.1(1)/fullcalendar-2.6.1/fullcalendar.css' />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https:/resources/demos/style.css">


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src='fullcalendar-2.6.1(1)/fullcalendar-2.6.1/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
    <script src='fullcalendar-2.6.1(1)/fullcalendar-2.6.1/fullcalendar.js'></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(

            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: +1, maxDate: "+1Y" });


            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                weekends:false,
                defaultView:'agendaWeek',
                header: {
                    left:'prev,today,next',
                    center:'title',
                    right:'month,agendaWeek'
                },
            });

     });
```

Comment: i wasn't able to copy/paste this to make it work. But it helped greatly!
and, yes. this is my first attempt at website design.